# Can't access Ubuntu drive after installing new primary windows 10 SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, ssd

So long story short, I need a way to reinstall the Ubuntu GRUB boot manager on my primary SSD. I currently have 3 storage drives in my laptop, a primary ssd with windows 10, a secondary ssd for Ubuntu 18.04, and a 3rd hdd for generic storage. I installed Ubuntu onto the 2nd drive using the dual boot after windows installation, which gave me an Ubuntu GRUB boot loader which worked fine. Problem is, I have just replaced my primary ssd, reinstalled a fresh windows 10 on it, but unfortunately have now lost all access to the Ubuntu installation on tje 2nd drive. I have tried various methods of modifying boot commmands, boot-repair etc, but have seemingly only made things worse (im now on my 3rd fresh windows 10 install after various crirital bsd's).
Does anyone have any suggestions? Or do I just need to give up and do a fresh Ubuntu install aswell? Heres a link to my boot-repair summary.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fm6dTwPVzB/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

by installing fresh Windows, you have removed bootloader options on the first SSD (where your last windows where) and by the way, if your grub was installed on the second SSD, you actually haven't lost your grub bootloader even! so try these solutions and let me know if that works:

## solution 1

try booting your system from the second SSD which your Ubuntu is installed on, if you ask how, you can do that by changing your boot options in BIOS setup ( could be accessed by pressing one of F1 to F12 or DEL key during turning on your laptop ) or if you have an ASUS laptop, pressing ESC key will bring up a menu to select boot option.

if that worked, congratulation! then you will be booted with grub and your Ubuntu, after that search for how to fix ubuntu grub ( like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) one ) and also it's possible to fix grub from within booted Ubuntu too.

## solution 2

Windows has its own bootloader, Ubuntu uses grub, and there are lot's of other bootloaders too! [super-grub2-disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) is one of them. you can [download](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) and make a bootable thumb drive, then boot your system with it and see if it recognize your Ubuntu installation.

if that worked, congratulation! do the same things explained for fixing grub.